# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setChannel' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a bot that's supposed to move members into a VC but I get this error TypeError:

> Cannot read property setChannel of undefined the full error is
> (node:3096) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function
> instead (node:3096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'setChannel' of undefined
> at C:\Users\mars\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:30:20
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) (node:3096)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:3096) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

The current code I have is

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.login("TOKEN");

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.info(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
});

function IDmaker(mention) {
  const ID = mention.replace(/[\\<>@#&!]/g, "");
  console.info(ID)
  return bot.users.get(ID);
}
bot.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.channel.id === '804144074902470666') {
    const args = message.content.slice(message.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const member = IDmaker(args[0]);
    console.info(member)
    message.guild.createChannel(`ticket-${message.author.id}`, {
      type: 'voice'
    }).then(c => {
      let role2 = message.guild.roles.find("name", "@everyone");
      c.overwritePermissions(role2, {
        SEND_MESSAGES: false,
        READ_MESSAGES: false
      });
      member.voice.setChannel(c)
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: `member` is a User. The `voice` property exists in the GuildMember class

Comment: What is `console.info(member)` printing ?

Comment: It prints User {
  id: '572570660417830912',
  username: 'YOMMOMA',
  discriminator: '9015',
  avatar: '39a055554c150d6d88085f35ffd4fe7d',
  bot: false,
  lastMessageID: null,
  lastMessage: null
}